# Inserting arrays into SQL table from form

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I was trying to insert arrays from my form, let's say for example I have select with options such as A, B, C, D, E for first select group, and 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for second select group. When selecting options from these two select group, I should have the values to be inserted as:

| letter | number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |

There's also a default number of 0 to be included during insertion.

I have tried this code I have seen:

```
    $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO letter_num_tag (default_zero, letter_tag, number_tag) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    foreach ($_POST as $row) {
        $statement->bind_param($row['default_zero_post'], $row['letter_tag_post'], $row['number_tag_post']);
        $statement->execute();
    }
```

However, this will result in this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: trim(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given
```

This is what my form submit looked like:

```
$default_zero_var = $_POST["default_zero_post"];
$letter_tag_var = $_POST['letter_tag_post'];
$number_tag_var = $_POST['number_tag_post'];

if (empty(trim($_POST["letter_tag_post"]))) {
    $letter_tag_var_err = "Please enter event date.";
} else {
    $letter_tag_var = trim($_POST["letter_tag_post"]);
}

if (empty(trim($_POST["number_tag_post"]))) {
    $number_tag_var_err = "Please enter event date.";
} else {
    $number_tag_var = trim($_POST["number_tag_post"]);
}
```

My form looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>A</li><input type='checkbox' name='letter_tag_post[]' value='A'>
<li>B</li><input type='checkbox' name='letter_tag_post[]' value='B'>
<li>C</li><input type='checkbox' name='letter_tag_post[]' value='C'>
<li>D</li><input type='checkbox' name='letter_tag_post[]' value='D'>
<li>E</li><input type='checkbox' name='letter_tag_post[]' value='E'>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1</li><input type='checkbox' name='number_tag_post[]' value='1'>
<li>2</li><input type='checkbox' name='number_tag_post[]' value='2'>
<li>3</li><input type='checkbox' name='number_tag_post[]' value='3'>
<li>4</li><input type='checkbox' name='number_tag_post[]' value='4'>
<li>5</li><input type='checkbox' name='number_tag_post[]' value='5'>
</ul>
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We don't know what your form or your POST data looks like. Please add info about that.

Comment: Oh, sorry @CBroe. I forgot to include my form. Thanks for commenting

Comment: you need to loop over each of the post variables as they themselves are arrays too, i imagine if you do a `var_dump($_POST)` you'll get an insight as to what is going on